# Error using plot. Not enough input arguments

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

For some reason I get the error in the title and i'm not really sure why. My code is suppose to plot one column of data against another, it gets up to the plot line of code before throwing this error:

```
trent2.mat
C:\Users\TrentPC\Documents\MATLAB\
Error using plot
Not enough input arguments.

Error in BioRadioGUI>pushPlot_Callback (line 546)
        plot(axisPoint(ch),savePoint(1:end-1,1),savePoint(1:end-1,ch+1));

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in BioRadioGUI (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)BioRadioGUI('pushPlot_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

Error while evaluating UIControl Callback
```

My code:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushPlot.
function pushPlot_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushPlot (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

[filename,pathname] = uigetfile('*.mat','Select the record file for feature extraction');
if filename == 0
    msgbox('Invalid File Selection','Error','error');
else
    clearvars savePoint 
    addpath(pathname)
    load(filename)
    disp(filename)
    disp(pathname)

    [rowPoint, columnPoint] = size(savePoint);

    axisPoint = zeros(1,columnPoint-2);

    figure

    for ch = 1:columnPoint-2
        axisPoint(ch) = subplot(columnPoint-2,1,ch);
    end

    hold on

    for ch = 1:columnPoint-2
        plot(axisPoint(ch),savePoint(1:end,1),savePoint(1:end,ch+1));
    end

end    

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

My data format:

```
time, value1, value2, value3, value4, label
```

What it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7i42.jpg

What the figure looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdwIt.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of solved the problem by converting the cell data into matrix form, for some reason plot doesn't like the cell form. I anyone is interested this is the code I used to rectify the problem.

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushPlot.
function pushPlot_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushPlot (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

[filename,pathname] = uigetfile('*.mat','Select the record file for feature extraction');
if filename == 0
    msgbox('Invalid File Selection','Error','error');
else
    clearvars savePoint rowPoint columnPoint
    addpath(pathname)
    load(filename)
    disp(filename)
    disp(pathname)

    [rowPoint, columnPoint] = size(savePoint);

    axisPoint = zeros(1,columnPoint-2);

    savePointFix = savePoint;

    savePointFix(:,columnPoint) = [];

    savePointPlot = cell2mat(savePointFix);

    figure

    for ch = 1:columnPoint-2
        axisPoint(ch) = subplot(columnPoint-2,1,ch);
    end

    hold on

    for ch = 1:columnPoint-2
        plot(axisPoint(ch),savePointPlot(:,1),savePointPlot(:,ch+1));
    end

end    

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```